# How does one use basic propositional rules in Isar to prove `A ⟶ A ∨ B`?

Tags: isabelle, isar

I wanted to transform this proof to Isar as ab exercise (for myself to learn Isar) using only basic natural deduction rules (ND) from propositional logic (e.g. `notI`, `notE`, `impI`, `impE`... etc).

I can do it in an apply script easily:

```
lemma very_simple0: "A ⟶ A ∨ B"
  apply (rule impI) (* A ⟹ A ∨ B *)
  thm disjI1 (* ?P ⟹ ?P ∨ ?Q *)
  apply (rule disjI1) (* A ⟹ A *)
  by assumption
```

but my attempts at an Isar proof fail:

```
lemma very_simple1: "A ⟶ A ∨ B"
proof (* TODO why/how does this introduce A by itself*)
  assume A (* probably not neccessary since Isabelle did impI by itself *)
  have "A ⟹ A" by disjI1
  show "A ⟹ A" by assumption
qed
```

my main error is:

```
Undefined method: "disjI1"⌂
```

which seems mysterious to me because the rules worked just fine in the apply script before.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Note this also leads to an error:

```
lemma very_simple2: "A ⟶ A ∨ B"
proof impI
  assume A (* probably not neccessary since Isabelle did impI by itself *)
  have "A ⟹ A" by disjI1
  show "A ⟹ A" by assumption
qed
```

same error as above:

```
Undefined method: "impI"⌂
```

why?

---

Edit:

I learned that a 'method' still requires the work `rule impI` or `metis etc` but the script still fails:

```
lemma very_simple1: "A ⟶ A ∨ B"
proof (rule impI)
  assume A (* probably not neccessary since Isabelle did impI by itself *)
  have "A ⟹ A" by (rule disjI1)
  show "A ⟹ A" by assumption
qed
```

---

Edit2:

```
lemma very_simple1: "A ⟶ A ∨ B"
proof (rule impI)
  have 0: "A ⟹ A ∨ B" by (rule disjI1)
  have 1: "A ⟹ A" by assumption
  from 1 show "True" by assumption
qed
```

I still can't complete the proof.

Comment: You still have to write `rule impI`, impI is not enough. Remark that "proof" is equivalent to "proof standard" and applies one theorem automatically.

Comment: @MathiasFleury ` have "A ⟹ A" by (rule disjI1)` this still doesn't work though. Why?

Comment: Because disjI1 is not the theorem you want! ``have "A ⟹ A" by assumption`` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems.

Let us consider the example:

```
have "A ⟹ A" by (rule disjI1)
```

That fails, so first what is the theorem disjI1 actually?

```
thm disjI1
(* ?P ⟹ ?P ∨ ?Q *)
```

Due to how rules works, it tries to match the goal "A" with "?P ∨ ?Q", which fails. Now, if your goal has the right form:

```
have "A ⟹ A ∨ B" by (rule disjI1)
```

it works!

Second problem:

```
 proof
```

is by default equivalent to "proof standard" and applies some theorem by default. Typically, you will use "proof -" to apply no theorem.

Lastly, let us consider your example

```
lemma very_simple1: "A ⟶ A ∨ B"
proof (rule impI)
```

In the state view, you see:

```
proof (state)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. A ⟹ A ∨ B
```

This means that the Isar must look like

```
lemma very_simple1: "A ⟶ A ∨ B"
proof (rule impI)
  assume ‹A›
  show ‹A ∨ B›
    sorry
qed
```

The fact that show works indicates that proof block has the correct form.

Beware: This is an important step especially at the beginning. ALWAYS start with the assume and the show. Do not wright anything else. If the show does not work, the structure induced by the Isar proof (assume and show) does not match the expected proof (which can be seen in the State panel).

You can do whatever you want from there (including starting a new proof block), but you cannot change that structure without changing which rule was applied.

Let's finish the proof. We want to use the assumption (so we add a `then`) and the rule to prove the goal.

```
lemma very_simple1: "A ⟶ A ∨ B"
proof (rule impI)
  assume ‹A›
  then show ‹A ∨ B›
    by (rule disjI1)
qed
```

Overall, I think you should read the Isar part of the [Concrete Semantics](http://concrete-semantics.org/).

EDIT: 
The most important problem is that you misunderstand what Isar is: Isar is not here to help you with the different proof steps (like proving tha "A ==> A"). It is here to do a forward proof: You start from the assumption (here A) and go to the conclusion. So the Isar proof will look like

```
  assume A
  show "A \/ B"
```

You never have to repeat the assumption A in the proof!

Comment: I am of course going through it but wanted to work a simpler example than Cantor's proof they give (that only uses single step proof methods). Why does my proof attempt still not work?

Comment: I expanded my answer a bit. Additionnaly, most Isabelle approaches try to teach a more automated style with auto and co. It is a good thing (and what you should do), but if you only interested in using `rule`, you can also read section 5 of the tutorial https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/tutorial.pdf

Comment: What is a "good thing"? Did you refer learning to use `auto` & `co`? I assume those are good for doing "real proofs" but I hate that they are black boxes. I have no idea what they are doing or how to implement one of my own.

Comment: Im curious, why are you putting the `<  >` in your proof?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems I don't understand Isar at all, specially considering that the "assumption" command/rule was not needed to complete the proof. Perhaps using their example (Cantor's Argument) and go through the chapter is the only practical way to learn Isar. Thanks for the help so far btw!

Comment: I prefer cartouches ‹› to quotes. It is a matter of style.

Using auto is the "right way" in Isabelle. It is a black box and you well never be able to guess what you will end up with (at least, I still don't). However, I would start with auto, follow the Concrete Semantics, and only later go for the manual proofs instead of fighting the book. It is the major difference in teaching between Isabelle and Coq.

Comment: What is the major difference in teaching Isabelle & Coq? Isabelle is more of a black box than Coq?

Comment: I am so fairly interested in understanding ATPs/Tactics and implement some myself. Is there a good place to learn about this for Isabelle?

Comment: Usually (and to caricature), after two hours of teaching Isabelle you prove the explicit form of $\sum_{k=0}^n k$ and in Coq you prove that $(P --> Q) --> P --> Q$. About tactics: you can read about Eisbach, but I believe the best way is to start proving with the tactics and then decide what you need that does not exist yet. Tactics are more widely used in Coq (e.g., see Chlipala's CPDT), because the base tactics are weaker.